# Give an option to resize image on image boundary HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yezq93fh/)

I want to give option to user to resize the image 
Like when the user drag arrow[around the image], the image should 
increase/decrease in size proportionately.

[image: Sample image]

how to allow user to drag arrow and increase size of image and see it simultaneously.

Sample Code

```
  <label>Upload your image here..</label>
                                  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
```

You text appears here..

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far.

Comment: You might want to listen to the event of drag (which you have to create by adapting the onmousedown and listening for x and y movement on the mouse while onmousedown). While you listen to that new event you refresh the image for each n pixels dragged by the user.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yezq93fh/

Comment: upload a file in the fiddle..You will see the image